# Build string from dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am storing my Database connection information in a Dictionary. Now i would like to create my sqlalchemy connection string from this dictionary `d`

```
d={"username":"max",
   "password":"admin",
   "server":"exampleserver",
   "port":"5050",
   "Database":"DB1"}
```

Is there a better way to convert a dictioniary to the string

```
mssql+pyodbc://max:admin@exampleserver:5050/DB1
```

than using string format

```
s="mssql+pyodbc://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(d['username'],d['password'],d['server'],d['port'],d['Database'])
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need the dictionary? You could write your own class and implement a string representation for it that fits your needs

Comment: `s="mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{Database}".format(**d)` see duplicate